# Can I attach IAM role and security group to AWS RedShift in free trial?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, aws-security-group

I'm using AWS free tier and try to create a Redshift cluster, when I select free trial while I'm creating the cluster, I can't attach an IAM role or a security group to the Redshift cluster.
Is that meaning I can't do this in the free trial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) for Amazon Redshift provides `750 DC2.Large node hours per month for 2 months`.

The "Free trial" configuration in the Amazon Redshift console provisions a matching cluster. You are correct that it offers minimal configuration options. However, **you can modify the cluster after it is launched** and attach an IAM Role and change Security Group.

Alternatively, launch the cluster via the **Production** option and simply make sure that you have selected a `dc2.large` node. You will not be billed for the first 750 node hours per month for two months.